# Counting the letters in a word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I want to convert my simple python code into JavaScript. In JavaScript, I noticed that the for loop is based of C and C++ syntax, thus

```
for( INITIALIZE; BOOLEAN EXPRESSION; ACTION)
  {  
  STATEMENT;   
  STATEMENT;
  }
```

I have this simple code (which just counts the characters in a string) that I want to covert to JavaScript

```
def countLetter(word, letter): 
  count = 0 
  for character in word:
    if letter ==  character:
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

In JavaScript

```
function countLetter(word, letter) {
    for (var characters in word){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 var count = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
      if(word.charAt(i) == letter) {
           count++;
      }
 }
```

`in` operator behaves differently in JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Comment: Mikko, what does word.charAt(i) do? Is it possible to translate the python code to Javascipt using the same iteration? Because I don't want to use build in functions that are in JavaScript.

Comment: Please read the given link. It is not possible. JavaScript strings do not have `in` operator.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa see after `var i=0:` here it should be semi colon, it may be mistyped by you

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `substr` in javascript:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
  if(word.substr(i,1) == letter) {
       count++;
  }
 }
```